# What is the function of @ at the command line after a file name

Tags: shell, autocomplete

I noticed that when I tab complete after `cat /home/@` I got some servers I have. Seems it's stuff I put in /etc/hosts.
But what is the function of @ in this case. Am I missing some handy pipe functionality?

I know it's also used for symbolic links and user:pass@server but in this case I have no clue.
Anyone can shine a light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, and possibly other shells, [tab-completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Completion.html#Commands-For-Completion) involving an `@` symbol will:

> Attempt to perform completion on the text before point. The actual completion performed is application-specific. Bash attempts completion treating the text as a variable (if the text begins with ‘$’), username (if the text begins with ‘~’), ***hostname (if the text begins with ‘@’)***, or command (including aliases and functions) in turn. If none of these produces a match, filename completion is attempted.

The code for bash is in `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, starting at the `_user_at_host` function.

Comment: Ahh ok, so you can username@ <- tab completion to server
So it does nothing with a dir / filename in front of it